# Table view not working smoothly with SDWebImage

Tags: performance, uitableview, sdwebimage

Why isn’t my table view not working smoothly? I use `SDWebImage` to set the image from a URL. I'm trying to draw 3 images in each row of the table view.

It works fine when `arrList` is small, but when I increase `arrList`, it becomes slower and slower (look like a little vibration when I scroll the table view).

This is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";
    CustomCellTable *cell = (CustomCellTable*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray * nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCellTable" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    [cell setBackgroundColor:brgColor];
    // item 1
    if ((indexPath.row*3) > arrList.count-1) return cell;
    vod *Item = [arrList objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row*3)];
    [cell.image1 setHidden:NO];
    [cell.image1 setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:Item.imageURl] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"poster_default.png"]];
    [cell makeRating:[Item.rating floatValue] positionOf:14];
    // item 2
    if ((indexPath.row*3 +1) > arrList.count-1) return cell;
    Item = [arrList objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row*3+1)];
    [cell.image2 setHidden:NO];
    [cell.image2 setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:Item.imageURl] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"poster_default.png"]];
    [cell makeRating:[Item.rating floatValue] positionOf:118];
    // item 3
    if ((indexPath.row*3 +2) > arrList.count-1) return cell;
    Item = [arrList objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row*3+2)];
    [cell.image3 setHidden:NO];
    [cell.image3 setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:Item.imageURl] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"poster_default.png"]];
    [cell makeRating:[Item.rating floatValue] positionOf:225];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: One quick adjustment you can make is to move the setBackgroundColor into the if (cell == nil) block, as that will be the same for every cell. Probably the images you're loading need to be scaled down before displaying to get a real benefit.

Comment: Did you use Instruments to find the bottle neck?

Comment: Thank you. I'll try Instruments.

Answer (score 0):

Look into down sampling the images so you're not storing/loading the large versions of the images while scrolling.

https://github.com/toptierlabs/ImageCacheResize

This library combines SDWebImage with UIImage+Resize. Using it instead of just SDWebImage might help. Specifically use the following method to load the images:

```
- (void)setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url andResize:(CGSize)size withContentMode:(UIViewContentMode)mode;
```

Comment: thank you. I tried SDWebImage with UIImage+Resize, but it seems slower to display images :(. And vibration still appears when I increase the arrList :(

Comment: ah :( hopefully instruments can help you out